# Can I associate two types with an implementation?

Tags: types, rust

I have a public trait in a library that is expected to use two structures for its implementation. One of the structs is public and is expected to be set up by the programmer, at which point they'll call the methods from the trait as they choose.

During that process, however, the public trait will make use of another struct (private) and implementation to do the job of the public implementation. All of that is 'under the hood', but I'd like to give the programmer the option to choose which strategy is used 'under the hood'.

Can I do this by associating an implementation with multiple types?

### Contrived Example

```
pub struct Court<T> {}

pub struct Field<T> {}

struct Football<T> {}

impl<T> Football<T> {}

struct SoccerBall<T> {}

impl<T> SoccerBall<T> {}

struct LacrosseBall<T> {}

impl<T> LacrosseBall<T> {}

struct Baseball<T> {}

impl<T> Baseball<T>{}

impl<T> Match<T> for Field<T>, Football<T> {}

impl<T> Match<T> for Field<T>, SoccerBall<T> {}

impl<T> Match<T> for Field<T>, LacrosseBall<T> {}

impl<T> Match<T> for Field<T>, Baseball<T> {}

impl<T> Match<T> for Court<T>, LacrosseBall<T>{}
```

In this case, I may want to implement a `Match` played with different balls, on different playing areas. At the outset, I want to give the programmer the chance to choose a ball, but I don't want to expose unneeded ball methods publicly.

The contrived example may seem like it invites the solution of adding a `Sport` type, but that's an artifact of the example, and I'd like to avoid adding more types if I can get away with it.

Comment: I don't really understand the example. Is there a relation between `Court<T>` and `Field<T>`?

Comment: @WesleyWiser No, I just wanted to show that there would be multiple structs that would be involved in this.

Comment: Ok. It looks to me like you're trying to have different implementations of `Match<T>` depending on the `Field<T>` and the activity being played on it right? I think you're either going to have to add a type parameter to `Field` for the game type or to `Match` for the game type.

Comment: I agree with @WesleyWiser: it's very hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish. You could likely remove all but two of the types, which should be enough. Additionally, you haven't defined what `Match` *is*. Please review what how to create a [MCVE]. **Showing us** code that is an "expose[d] unneeded ball method" would also go a long way.

Comment: Which of the two types would be the private one and which the public one, the balls or the fields?

Comment: Are you looking for `impl<T> Match<T, Football<T>> for Field<T> { … }`?